# Как сделать чтобы участник с определённой ролью на дискорд сервере мог кикать/банить определённое колличество раз в день?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Как сделать чтобы участник с определённой ролью на дискорд сервере мог кикать/банить определённое колличество раз в день(например 3 раза в день)? Это можно сделать в самом дискорде или придётся создавать бота? Если бота, то как?

Answer (score 1):

```py
@commands.cooldown(rate=3, per=86400, type=commands.BucketType.role)
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason: str = None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        description=f'Пользоваетель {member} был забанен по причине **{reason}**!', 
        color=discord.Color.blurple()))

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            description=f'Вы не указали параметр `{error.param.name}`',
            color=discord.Color.blurple()))
    else:
        raise error
```

Здесь надо обратить внимание на декоратор `commands.cooldown`

- Параметр rate отвечает за то, сколько раз может пользователь использовать эту команду за определенный отрезок времени.
- Параметр per отвечает за тот самый промежуток времени.
- Параметр type отвечает за "фильтр", т.е., по какому признаку отличать пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

В самом дискорде это сделать нельзя , это надо писать бота ( вот можешь прочитать https://dev-gang.ru/article/kak-sozdat-discord-bota-s-pomosczu-python-uhacexvap5/ )